# Prove that $\frac{(x+2)^p-2^p}{x}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z[x]}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, ring-theory, factoring, irreducible-polynomials

Prove that $\frac{(x+2)^p-2^p}{x}$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z[x]}$

Can I get some help with this one? I mean my gut is obviously telling me to start with a binomial expansion, but I just don't know where to go from there. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{(x+2)^p-2^p}{x}=x^{p-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{n}2^{p-n}x^{n-1}$$
where $p\mid\binom pn$ for $0<n<p$ and $p^2\nmid \binom{p}{1}2^{p-1}$ if $p\neq 2$, hence [Eisestein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) applies.

On the other hand, for $p=2$ then $\frac{(x+2)^p-2^p}{x}$ has degree $1$ hence it's irreducible.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Eisenstein's irreducibility criterion.